# How can i retrieve multiple data from remote php in nativescript javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, user-interface, frontend, nativescript

I'm trying to retrieve multiple data from my remote php file and display them dynamically, i usually do this with jquery when i'm coding cordova. i'm using nativescript now.
This is the jquery code i use before

```
$.getJSON(serviceURL + 'getroutes.php?station='+station, function(data) {
        employees = data.items;
        $.each(employees, function(index, employee) {
            $('#employeeList').append('<li>'+
                    '<img src="js/citybus.png" class="list-icon"/>' +
                    '<p class="line1">' + employee.firstName + '</p>' +
                    '<p class="line2">' + difference + ' Out' + '</p>' +
                    '<p class="line3" style="color:'+ color +';margin-left:60px">' + SeatsLeft + ' seats left </p>' +
                    '<button style="display:'+ display +'" class="bubble" data-difference="' + hoursMin + '" data-route="' + employee.firstName + '" data-busnum="' + employee.lastName + '" onclick="bookSeat(this);">' + '<center><img src="js/seat.jpg" style="height:15px;width:15px;"/></center>' + '</button>'
                    + '<button data-id="' + employee.id + '" data-diff="' + hoursMin + '" data-name="' + employee.firstName + '" class="bubble" style="margin-right:30px" onclick="setReminder(this);">' + '<center><img src="js/bell.png" style="height:15px;width:15px;"/></center>' + '</button></li>');

            if(index && index % 4 === 0) {
                $('#employeeList').append('<center><div class="adSpace2" style="margin-top:2.5px;margin-bottom:2.5px;">'+'</div></center>');
            }

        });
        setTimeout(function(){
            scroll.refresh();
        });
    });
```

**Please how do i do this with nativescript?**

Comment: I would suggest you to understand the jQuery code then you could figure out the equivalent {N} code yourself. You are hitting the API, reading the array, looping through it to render a list. Coming to {N} or native mobile apps development, you would avoid rendering elements manually for a long list but use ListView, define the template and then play with data - https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/components/list-view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

```
const Observable = require('tns-core-modules/data/observable').Observable
const model = new Observable()

function loaded(args) {
    args.object.bindingContext = model
    fetch(serviceURL + 'getroutes.php?station='+station).then(res => model.set('employees', res.items))
}
exports.loaded = loaded
```

And then in your View XML:

```
<Page xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" xmlns:lv="nativescript-ui-listview" aloaded="loaded">
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView items="{{employees}}">
            <Label class="line1" text="{{firstName}}" />
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

Comment: how can i display the data?

Comment: @kunlee see my updated answer.  NOTE: It is untested but it will hopefully give you enough information that you can use to add the rest of your code.

Comment: the data i'm retrieving is JSON, will this still work?

Comment: Yes.  `fetch()` should automatically convert your JSON data into a JavaScript object.